Horizontally Centre a Custom Liquid Button in a Container using Custom CSS or alter HTML code
I have the following custom liquid button:


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="image" src="https://my.payfast.io/images/buttons/Subscribe/Dark-Large-Subscribe.png" alt="Subscribe" title="Subscribe with Payfast" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



I have been trying for days to read previous posts on how to horizontally center this button on my page without success?
Can someone please help me to either update the HTML code or use CSS custom section to center the button horizontally on its container on my web page?

Your button is already centered inside it's container, but your container is not 100% wide

Thanks so how can I edit the code to make the container 100% wide?

Tables by default do not occupy 100% of width. You need to define that exclusively:


<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="image" src="https://my.payfast.io/images/buttons/Subscribe/Dark-Large-Subscribe.png" alt="Subscribe" title="Subscribe with Payfast" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Besides I suggest a simple <div style="text-align:center"> insetad.

By default table element is not blocked full-width of the parent element. just make your table width 100% and the button will be aligned center horizontally.
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="image" src="https://my.payfast.io/images/buttons/Subscribe/Dark-Large-Subscribe.png" alt="Subscribe" title="Subscribe with Payfast" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

